# Click button using curl

Tags: linux, curl, wget

I need to fetch contact number from an URL, may be using curl.

Sample link- https://www.olx.pl/oferta/philips-sluchawki-bezprzewodowe-shc5100-CID99-IDiER3w.html#188a0d656b

Contact number button in on right hand side & value is hidden. Once you click on it, value shows up. There is no onclick event on button. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with combination of curl, sed and grep command outputs.

Here is an example:

```
wget -q -O - $(echo http://www.olx.pl/ajax/misc/contact/phone/$(curl -s  https://www.olx.pl/oferta/philips-sluchawki-bezprzewodowe-shc5100-CID99-IDiER3w.html#188a0d656b | grep link-phone | egrep -oh \'id\'\:\'\\S+\' | tail -n 1 | sed -e s/\'id\'\://g | sed -e s/\'//g))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not producing any output.

Comment: Looks like grep (color) was adding some inquired characters. That was making it fail. I further piped the curl output to remove those characters, as `curl -s <URL> | grep link-phone | egrep -oh \'id\'\:\'\\S+\' | tail -n 1 | sed -e s/\'id\'\://g | sed -e s/\'//g | perl -pe 's/\x1b.*?[mGKH]//g'`. It works like a charm now. Thanks @mariuszs80